# Why does Spring SAML-based app throw exception only on remote server?

Tags: java, spring, saml, adfs

I have java app based on spring-security-saml2-core and org.opensaml:opensaml which utilizes SSO-auth process through ADFS server. This app works as I expected on my localhost PC, but it throws exception

```
AuthNResponse;FAILURE;10.*.*.0;localhost-demo;***;;;org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Response doesn't have any valid assertion which would pass subject validation
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:229)
```

when this app deployed to K8s-cluster.

According to text of this exception I checked Assertions in response and I'm pretty sure that it exists

```
 <Assertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_e7095784-5ea3-4cf2-aef1-8551ebfa1cf5" IssueInstant="2020-10-07T20:26:59.971Z" Version="2.0">
```

Has whoever met the same problem ?

Comment: does the assertion contain "Subject" information? Are the outgoing claim rules correctly defined in ADFS to send some value as the Name ID (which usually  will appear in the Subject section)?

Comment: You may need get more details via opensaml debug logging, e.g. it could be related to a clock skew issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33408854/response-doesnt-have-any-valid-assertion-which-would-pass-subject-validation